# How do I make Angular 2 final (2.0.0, after rc7) and TestBed work in this Plunkr?

Tags: unit-testing, angular, plunker

I just want to initiate TestBed, so I can use TestBed functions. I am trying this in my src/test.spec.ts and it is not working:

```
TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
```

I also tried doing a System.import for TestBed and it didn't work. For example, this didn't work as a script tag in index.html.

```
Promise.all([
    System.import('@angular/core/testing'),
    System.import('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing')
]).then(function (providers) {
    var testing = providers[0];
    var testingBrowser = providers[1];
   testing.TestBed.initTestEnvironment(testingBrowser.BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
        testingBrowser.platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
}).then(function() {
    return Promise.all(
            return System.import(app/test.spec.ts); //"app" stands for // './src' in the config.js file for SystemJS
        );
})
```

Here is the Plunkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/K0IyBnR8F4F7zOp6LETi?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Seems you forgot about `rxjs` and you need also to update `zonejs` and include some other `zonejs` scripts:

**config.json**

```
map: {
  'app': './src',
  'typescript': 'npm:typescript@1.8.0/lib/typescript.js',
  '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core@2.0.0/bundles/core.umd.js',
  '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common@2.0.0/bundles/common.umd.js',
  '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler@2.0.0/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser@2.0.0/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
  '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http@2.0.0/bundles/http.umd.js',
  '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router@2.0.0/bundles/router.umd.js',
  '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms@2.0.0/bundles/forms.umd.js',
  '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade@2.0.0/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
  '@angular/core/testing': 'npm:@angular/core@2.0.0/bundles/core-testing.umd.js',
  '@angular/common/testing': 'npm:@angular/common@2.0.0/bundles/common-testing.umd.js',
  '@angular/compiler/testing': 'npm:@angular/compiler@2.0.0/bundles/compiler-testing.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser@2.0.0/bundles/platform-browser-testing.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js',
  '@angular/http/testing': 'npm:@angular/http@2.0.0/bundles/http-testing.umd.js',
  '@angular/router/testing': 'npm:@angular/router@2.0.0/bundles/router-testing.umd.js',
  '@angular/forms/testing': 'npm:@angular/forms@2.0.0/bundles/forms-testing.umd.js',

  'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs'
},
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.25/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.25/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.25/dist/async-test.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.25/dist/fake-async-test.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.25/dist/sync-test.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.25/dist/proxy.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.25/dist/jasmine-patch.min.js"></script>
```

Besides that you have an error in your component:

**src/component.ts**

```
export class myCmp {
  this._testVar = "initial value";
```

You should remove `this.`

Here's **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/C5GSXC3Pt3dgLNeIvNKR?p=preview)** for your case. Hope it will help you!

Comment: Thank you sooooo much! I don't have enough reputation to give you best answer.

Comment: Hi yurzui, can you show me how that plunkr would work if a child component on the template had to be updated.

Comment: Can you answer this question please - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40160036/angular-2-unit-tests-child-components-template-does-not-change-when-parent-c

Comment: Thanks yurzui! Doesn't work in my real code though :(. I use a MockChildComponent instead of the parent component, but I just tried to do this with the real ChildComponent and it didn't work either.

Comment: *I meant, I use a MockChildComponent instead of the real child component.

Comment: Thanks yurzui, it did work in my test at least for normal child components. I will be asking you something again shortly, this is when the child component directive is bound to a div or tr, for example:    <tr class="child-cml-selector" *ngFor="let _data of _rows"
                    [_study]="_data">
                </tr>

Comment: *child-cmp-selector. This in the parent component's template. So I want _data to change for each child component it is assigned to, when the parent component's method is called. I will post the Plunkr here shortly.

Comment: *it did work in my test for child components and mock child components, when we have <child-cmp><child-cmp> on page. Rather than bind the child component to a class.

Comment: Hey yurzui, please help me make this Plunkr work, same child component being assigned to class. https://plnkr.co/edit/dH5UVuqQOhBrSbqjZekN?p=preview

Comment: I am sorry for lack of edits hence many comments, could not figure out how to edit existing comments. The same Plunkr right above this comment and what I request you to do, is in this Stackoverflow question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40162607/angular-2-unit-tests-child-component-template-not-updating-when-child-component