# Angular 2 unit testing: Make ngFor rendered, child components' templates change?

Tags: unit-testing, angular

I have something like this in my parent component's template (the parent component is being tested).

```
<div *ngFor="let data of _dataRows; let i=index">
    <child-cmp [data]="data"></child-cmp>
</div>

<button (click)="sortDataRows()"></button>
```

When I click the button in the test, the data rows are sorted in the parent component (component being tested). But the child components' order on the template is not changed. Without `ngFor`, the child components do get their templates updated in my code, when a method is called on the parent component being tested.

Here is the `sortDataRows()` method in my parent component (and yes, everything works in the application!):

```
private sortDataRows(sortValues: any): void {
    this._dataRows.sort(function(a: any, b: any): number{
        if (!a[sortValues.fieldName] || !b[sortValues.fieldName]) {
            //this will handle sorting of Null or undefined for any type
            return this.compareNullvalues(a[sortValues.fieldName], b[sortValues.fieldName], sortValues.ascending);
        }
        if (a[sortValues.fieldName] instanceof Date || Number.isInteger(a[sortValues.fieldName])) {
            return this.compareNumbersOrDates(a[sortValues.fieldName], b[sortValues.fieldName], sortValues.ascending);
        } else {
            return this.compareStringValues(a[sortValues.fieldName], b[sortValues.fieldName], sortValues.ascending);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code for the component and test code

Comment: Just did, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is currently an open bug on Angular - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12642